# Conditionally Replace Default Null Values from Left Join

Tags: sql, sas

I am joining 3 tables. In tables 2 and 3, records do not exist for some of the IDs in table 1. This of course, yields null values for these instances in my joined table.

I know I can replace these nulls with coalesce, but I don't know how to replace the nulls conditionally. In my reprex below, I would like to replace a null with an ID's max total (if an ID has a non-null total under a different job title) or replace a null with 0 (if an ID has null totals under both of their job titles).

[image]

[image]

Reprex code below:

```
/*sample table a (contains full data - 2 records for each ID)*/
data table_a;
input id title $ region $ calls;
cards;
1 manager south 30
1 agent north 20
2 manager west 20
2 agent south 25
;
run;

/*sample table b (missing an agent record for ID 1 -- will result in null total sales for ID 1's agent record in joined table)*/
data table_b;
input id title $ sales;
cards;
1 manager 20
2 manager 5
2 agent 3
;
run;

/*sample table c (missing both records for ID 2 - will result in null total_leads for ID 2 in joined table)*/
data table_c;
input id title $ leads;
cards;
1 manager .
1 agent 10
;
run;

/*join tables*/
proc sql;
create table reprex as

select a.id, 
       a.region, 
       a.calls, 
       a.title, 
       coalesce(b.total_sales, 0) as total_sales,   /*this replaces all nulls as 0, but I'd like to replace  
       b.sales,                                       them conditionally */
       coalesce(c.total_leads, 0) as total_leads, 
       c.leads
from table_a as a 

left join (select sum(coalesce(sales, 0)) as total_sales, sales, id, title from table_b group by id) b
on a.id = b.id and a.title = b.title

left join (select sum(coalesce(leads, 0)) as total_leads, leads, id, title from table_c group by id) c 
on a.id = c.id and a.title = c.title;
quit;
```

Comment: You need to explain what "nulls" you are talking about.  Post some example input and desired output.  Explain which nulls are which.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post to provide better comments as well as current and desired output.

Comment: Your tables seem to only have one observation per ID/TITLE combination? Why not just MERGE the three tables?

Comment: It is still hard to understand.  The photograph has text that seems to be saying the logic somehow depends on the values of TITLE?  Agent versus Manager somehow?  Can you explain the actual rule?

Comment: I'm unsure why you would like to use conditional logic rather than using coalesce. If it's an academic exercise then that makes sense, but coalesce is what you'd do in practice.

Comment: The logic was:
If total is null and id's max total is null, then replace with 0.
If total is null and id's max total is not null, then replace with max total.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up nesting subqueries to get what I was after:

```
proc sql;
create table reprex as

select id, region, title, 
calls, 
case 
    when max_total_calls is null then 0
    else max_total_calls
end as total_calls,
sales, 
case 
    when max_total_sales is null then 0
    else max_total_sales
end as total_sales,
leads,
case 
    when max_total_leads is null then 0
    else max_total_leads
end as total_leads
from
(select *,
max(total_sales) as max_total_sales,
max(total_leads) as max_total_leads, 
max(total_calls) as max_total_calls
from 
(select a.id, a.region, a.calls, a2.total_calls, a.title, 
b.sales, c.total_leads, c.leads
from table_a as a 

left join (select sum(coalesce(calls, 0)) as total_calls, calls, id, title from table_a group by id) a2
on a.id = a2.id and a.title = a2.title

left join (select sum(coalesce(sales, 0)) as total_sales, max(coalesce(sales,0)) as max_sales, sales, id, title from table_b group by id) b
on a.id = b.id and a.title = b.title

left join (select sum(coalesce(leads, 0)) as total_leads, leads, id, title from table_c group by id) c
on a.id = c.id and a.title = c.title)

group by id);
quit;
```